# App not showing up in Google Play Store for Galaxy S8+ (model G955U), what can be the problem?

Tags: android, google-play, react-native, google-play-console

I have an app in `Google Play`, which has such configuration:

```
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.0'
    supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
```

One of the potential user which has  Galaxy S8+ (model G955U) can't see my app in `Google Play`.
I checked the list of the supported devices in `Google Play` for my app and I see that other model of Galaxy S8+ is supported, but this particular model (model G955U) is not. User has latest OS on his phone. 
What can be the problem? What should I do so my app can support this phone model as well?

[image]

Comment: Are you using <supports-screens> or <compatible-screens>?

Comment: @Nik no, I don't use them

Comment: Try to clear google play store cache and data and uninstall it's updates and restart your device and then check. 

Even you are not getting solution you can to contact Google play support for this issue. Also you can submit your app to Samsung Developers account and they will test your app and will let you know what is actual reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent direct link to the app in Google Play to the user, which couldn't find our app in Google Play, and it turns out that there was problem with age restriction, the app is classified as social network (which means that only users which older than 13 can install it), even though the user was older then 13 in her phone settings she choose option to see only applications which available for all ages, after user changed this setting it was possible to install app through Google Play.